# Android Room does not allow database operations on Main UI thread but allows main thread to wait for other threads doing same, why so?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-room

I am using Room library in my android application for database operations, Room does not allow doing database operations on the main UI thread which is fine but if I do the same database operations on other new thread (triggered from Main UI thread) and wait for this new thread (say by using future.get() in main thread), then this is allowed. Why so?

Comment: Because Room has no way of detecting that case.

Comment: @CommonsWare I think I got the Idea, Room can check if the executing thread is Main UI thread or not (probably using Looper). If it is not, then it allows database operations. Thanks for your input on this.

Comment: Right. Room has no means of knowing that you happen to be blocking some other thread (such as the main application thread) waiting on a Room-supplied thread. The check that it has is just to try to prevent some obvious cases -- it's not a foolproof system.